# значение в переменной

Tags: c++

Подскажите плиз

```
std::string str; // объявили переменную типа стринг 
FunctionName(param_1, param_2, &str); // функция добавила в строку символы 
// после выполнения FunctionName переменная str = "hello"


unsigned char* charArr = (unsigned char*)str.c_str(); 
// charArr что то из следующего = 
//      {0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f}      - есть там ноль или нет ноля ?
// или  {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}     - если есть 0 то каким символом или кодом символа он представлен ? 
// или  {0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, ???} - если есть 0 то каким символом или кодом символа он представлен ?
```

теперь если  `str = "";`
`charArr` так же не содержит символов

Что происходит  - компилятор оптимизировал присвоив `charArr` ссылку или указатель на `str` ???
Как правильно задать значение `charArr` чтобы после изменения `str` - `charArr` не оказался так же изменённым ???

Comment: Учитывая, что `charArr` является указателем, было бы удивительно ожидать, что компилятор сделал бы что-то, отличное от присваивания указателя... После изменения `str = "";` `charArr` никаким образом не изменяется, но хранящееся в нем значение становится невалидным, а попытки разыменования являются неопределенным поведением. Правильным будет создать копию строки.

Comment: Функция `c_str` класса `string` возвращает указатель на приватный буфер класса. Чтобы не менялись значения буфера не меняйте строку или копируйте себе сразу все данные.

Comment: @AlexGlebe как правильно скопировать данные в  `unsigned char* charArr` или `unsigned char charArr[]`  - чтобы можно было изменять `str`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос : как правильно скопировать данные в `unsigned char* charArr` или `unsigned char charArr[]` - чтобы можно было изменять `str`

создаёте массив нужного размера + 
дополнительный байт для конца строки `'\00'`

```
unsigned char* charArr = new unsigned char[str.size()+1];
```

копируете строку в массив

```
memcpy(charArr,str.c_str(),str.size()+1);
```

Comment: так получилось  
    `unsigned char charArr[] = " ";`  
    `memcpy(charArr,str.c_str(),str.size()+1);`  
    `str = "";`

Comment: нужно обязательно выделять память. У вашего примера всё обрушится из-за неправомерного обращения к памяти.

Comment: да  - исправил как вы написали  - все работает так как хотел . Спасибо